# How to write an application to have as close to real -time characteristics as possible?

Tags: time, hardware, real-time

I'm looking for the best way to design an application that needs to respond in as close to real-time as possible. I have considered using a cut down kernel and building the software directly into that but I don't think that will be the best solution.

I am interested in creating something in hardware (I've been reading about that here on SO) and wondered if anyone had built something similar and if so what hardware did they use?

For example, is there a device that has gigabit Ethernet that is also programmable? i.e. a CPU on the card? I could then write a kernel driver to communicate / control the app running on the card - which would have lower latency making decisions based on network traffic due to its close proximity to the network interface...

Has anyone done this? If so can anyone recommend any hardware / software I should be looking into?

Comment: This is up to the OS, if you have a non-real-time OS, there is not much you can do...

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on your requirements?  You talk as if you need a real-time hardware solution, but want it to run as a peripheral on a desktop/server/laptop.  Is that correct?

Comment: I currently process the data in a user-land C application. However it is proving quite difficult to get the response times we need as the application is often preempted by the kernel. The reason I thought about a dual hardware / software solution was so that the hardware would be able to focus on the task without interruption. By writing a driver for it, it would be possible to read statistics and information in user-land which would also allow a means of controlling and fine tuning the app running on the card. I guess like how a GPU is used to offload graphics processing to free-up the CPU.

Comment: @Pete: I'd work on getting the OS/scheduler to do their job first... definitely lower impact.  Are you scheduling the tasks at real-time priorities?  What are the task execution times?  What latency bound are you looking for? Are your compute threads blocking (mutexes?) for any reason?

Comment: @andersoj I've tried running the threads with real-time priorities but whilst that improved the response times, they still weren't ideal and the response times themselves fluctuated significantly ( +/- 20ms ). Thus I'm looking for a blue sky solution. Assuming that I want a guaranteed response time of 0.5ms (which I do see on a good day), what is the best way to build it?

Comment: @Pete:  I guess I'd identify the logic path you need to get to 0.5ms and then work the following... 1) Do it in userspace and work to get everything out of the way -- PREEMPT_RT kernel, RT prios, use processor affinity if possible, etc.  Measure measure measure to determine source of preemption (+20ms sounds like a solvable hiccup somewhere); 2) split the problem into two physical processors, get anything non-essential off the RT; 3) move the time-sensitive logic into kernelspace; finally 4) implement a hardware solution.  I can only help a little with (4), mostly because 1-3 often work.

Comment: @Pete:  You could consider the use of a TOE (TCP Offload Engine) which drives latencies down predictably.  If you are going on a campaign that will take you to ever-lower latencies, it may be that IP is not your friend, and you should consider a targeted approach like raw ethernet or some special purpose bus (GPIB?) depending on the application.

Answer (score 3):

### General comments

You probably need to be more specific about your requirements before folks can answer.  Many of us have built real-time systems, but remember a) real-time is not the same as real-fast, and b) "real-time" is an umbrella term for a bunch of different timeliness criteria.

What activities do you need to ensure the timeliness of?  The solutions you propose in your question are mildly exotic, and should only be considered once you state your requirements and you're sure more conventional approaches are inadequate.

Building a real-time application / system is not dissimilar from designing anything else.  However, you do need to capture the timeliness requirements of each activity with the same precision that you ordinarily capture "functional" requirements (e.g., function/method pre, post, and invariant conditions).  The hard part comes when you begin to understand the sum of all these requirements as the pieces come together -- and this is less like other aspects of system design.

Even if you can't apply it in all its rigorous detail, I suggest an attempt to frame your application's activities in terms of an [RMA analysis](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/library/abstracts/reports/91tr006.cfm).  Many dynamic applications won't succumb completely to the analysis because you don't have enough data (they are inherently uncertain/dynamic/non-deterministic) but an attempt to apply the discipline will help.

In any case, start with analysis, not with a handful of sexy (and complicated) solutions...

Some things you should capture:

- What are the natural tasks/activities you expect the system to perform (in the problem space)?  This is a good place to start with your design, but your implementation may need to shift.
- What are the resources you need to manage? (CPU? Network?  Memory?)
- Can you ensure the resources will remain underloaded?  If not, you'll need to institute some feasibility analysis and [admission control policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admission_control) or "load shedding."  Note that this captures one dimension of "importance" or "priority" and is best decoupled from the other dimension...
- What are the time constraints?  This is the "urgency" dimension.  It may be a latency req't, or whatever.  Are these constraints hard or soft?  Aggregate or per-task?  (For an interesting and in-depth look at scheduling approaches that distinguish urgency and importance, see [RKC's thesis](http://www.real-time.org/docs/rkc-thesis.pdf) (or a [shorter summary](http://www.real-time.org/docs/rkc-thesis-summary.pdf)) from CMU, but take a deep breath before proceeding...)
- How are you going to represent the time constraint context of each activity in your implementation?  Note there is not a "deadline scheduler" for the CPU in most common OS'es, and the normal approach is to map urgencies onto priorities (see RMA) but this only works if the resource is underloaded.
- How do you want to handle the multi-resource challenges?  There is little in the way of rigorous analytical tools to help here, usually the goal is to overprovision as much as possible and apply admission control at the system boundaries.  If this is a system where you demand timeliness for activities that include network transmission AND processing, then you might look to apply admission control in the form of QoS traffic management, reducing (not removing) the need to worry about CPU loading.
- What are your throughput requirements?
- What are your activities' arrival patterns?  e.g., can you ensure a minimum inter-arrival time?
- What level of confidence do you require that your system / application will perform correctly?

### Edits based on additional comments

Before moving to a hybrid hw/sw approach, make sure you exhaust the software solutions first.  If your tasks are getting pre-empted by the kernel, then you should work to get that under control.

What is the OS?  If Linux, recent Windows, or Mac OS X, you should be able to schedule your processing threads at real-time priority, and minimize kernel-induced preemption.  If you are really burning up a CPU, maybe you should look at a dual-CPU approach, where you wall off a single CPU for your application processing (again, depends on OS).

Aha, 0.5ms response time starts to clarify the situation a bit.   If you're using a general purpose OS, consistent sub-ms latencies can be a bit challenging alright.

What processor (and clock speed?)

It sounds like you have some working (or close to it) code in place.  You've done some amount of analysis because you think preemption is killing you.  What steps have you taken to eliminate preemption?  Is the "decision" activity you reference a very small/simple evaluation?  Is it deterministic?  Is the 0.5ms bound a physical bound, or levied due to a latency budget that includes other pieces of the system?

Comment: The reason I said real time instead of low latency was because I need a response in the 0.5ms range. Anything after that would not be useful. I have tried to create this with a user-land application but too much is going on for it to reliably be this responsive. The application receives a data feed, makes a decision and then sends an appropriate response. My aim is to move the decision / response closer to the device so that that the operating system and user-land applications will have limited effect on the decision / response cycle.

Comment: Is this a one-off application, or something you need to build to scale?  I guess my next step would be to migrate (only absolutely necessary) things into a kernel driver as you suggest, and only after profiling that, consider a move to fancy HW solutions.

Comment: Scaling isn't a big issue for this application and I agree that a hardware solution is a big leap from hacking the kernel (which in itself is not for the faint of heart). I will look into writing it into the kernel again. The reason I started looking for alternatives was because I read that there wasn't much benefit to putting things in the kernel over user-land and it can cause significant issues and be hard to debug - though presumably not harder than a hardware device... Currently I'm using Linux 2.6

Comment: @Pete, I agree with the general sense that you can do pretty well in userspace, and moving things into the kernel willy-nilly is bad for any number of reasons.  Is this TCP/UDP?  Raw ethernet?

Comment: The data feed is TCP but the application works in a restricted environment in that I wouldn't need to implement a full TCP stack on the device itself. Is the suggestion of a hardware solution feasible? Admittedly it's a lot of work (great learning experience though) but I don't any hands on experience with it i.e. where would I even look for such a device. Basically a programmable gigabit Ethernet card I guess.

Comment: CPU is dual, core i7's @ 3.2Ghz. The decision logic is pretty simple, you could do it with pen and paper. It should be deterministic in that the complexity of the task never changes so it should take the same time for any input.